# Using PHP Xpath loop to to get current value as a variable

Tags: php, xpath

Here is my xml:

```
<publications>
  <publicationsgroup>
    <publicationsgroupheading><![CDATA[2013]]></publicationsgroupheading>
    <publicationslist>
      <publicationdetails> some text1.....</publicationdetails>
      <publicationdetails> some text2.....</publicationdetails>
    </publicationslist>
  </publicationsgroup>
<publications/>
```

In my php code I want to loop through the publicationdetails elements and assing the current value to a varaible.

Here's my php code:

```
foreach($publicationsgroupheadingyear->publicationslist as $publicationslistbyyear ) 
{
    foreach($publicationslistbyyear->publicationdetails as $publicationdetailsbyyear) 
    {
        $publicationDetailsValue = $publicationslistbyyear->publicationdetails; 
    }
}
```

I can only seeem to get the first value ('some text1') in $publicationDetailsValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're looping over all `<publicationdetails/>`, but not using that value.

Use the inner loop variable instead.

```
    $publicationDetailsValue = $publicationdetailsbyyear;
```

Comment: THank you, that works great.  I thought i had tried using the inner loop but with '->publicationdetails' on the end which was giving me nothing!